# C for and while loop randomly repeat themself

Tags: c

I have a program that should sum up the numbers (not digits!) in a text file.
It's something like:
(i iterates the string)

```
char str[] = "some random stuff with numbers 20001, 20002, 20003";
int count = 4; //length of number eg. 4
while(count > -1)
{
     num += (str[i - count] - '0') * (int)pow(10, count);
     count -= 1;
     printf("%i \n", count);
     if(count < 0)
        break;
}
```

runs 6 times
count = 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0

To check if I'm stupid, I added the printf statement and it really says count is -1 and it still repeats itself once but only once and not in every case. Something around 50% (not alternating).
First i had for-loop... Doesn't work.
Then i changed count-- to count -= 1... same thing.
Then i added the if-statement... doesn't work either. 
If you want to read the whole code:
https://pastebin.com/X3wCs4cF (parts are in german cause I'm from there and the task requires me to write it that way)
Glhf

Comment: `int count;` You need to initialize this. Ex `int count = 0;`

Comment: What value do you think `count` has when your loop starts?

Comment: The code in the pastebin is very different than the one you've posted there. You should post the relevants parts of the code (In fact, `count` was initialized)

Comment: Please start from the original code and remove/replace uninteresting parts until you have a minimal program that can reproduce the problem, preferably with hard-coded input data. BTW: Instead of `for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) if(str[i] == c)` you could use `if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))` or `if(isascii(str[i]) && isupper(str[i]))`

Comment: You could use RegEx to capture the numbers in your string and then, convert to int. Would be easier

Comment: yeah i know but it worked and i didn't want to touch a running system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `count`:

```
int count; // defined, but not initialized
while(count > -1)   // undefined behaviour here; accessing an uninitialized value
```

This should work:

```
int count = 5;
while(count > -1) ...
```

Comment: i did initialize it. It was just an example it's getting initialized earlier in the program which i didn't show for simplicity reasons. That's the reason i added the comment "eg. 4". You can look it up at pastebin

Comment: @FlorianBecker: A [MCVE] needs to include the minimal reproducer in the body of the question itself, not just by reference to an external site. Part of the idea is that, in attempting to minimize your code, you are likely to figure out your problem.

Comment: Now i edited it. See my problem now?

Comment: I just see that you use a variable `i`, where the code does not show how it is initialized.

Comment: maybe i should post the whole code, i guess...